# Dual AC Power Input on Audio Amplifier Board

Tags: ac

I'm confused as to what kind of transformer I should use to power this board. The manufacturer states the operating voltage as follows: AC12X2 to AC22X2.

Should I assume a phase shift of 180 degrees?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I assume a phase shift of 180 degrees?

Yes. The LM1875 uses a split supply. You need a transformer with a center-tapped secondary in the range 12-0-12 V to 22-0-22 V. The primary should suit your local AC mains supply, of course.

Does the board manufacturer suggest a suitable current/VA rating for the transformer? If not there is an application note on power supply design [here](http://www.ti.com/product/LM1875/technicaldocuments).